# What's the difference between FileList and File[] (aka. Array of File)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, drag-and-drop

When I receive file drops in a Browser, I get a [FileList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList) object. What's the purpose of this type? As far as I can see, it is nearly the same as a Typescript `File[]` or a good old JavaScript array of file objects.

From what I could find, FileList is inferior since you cannot iterate over values or indices using one of

```
for (let file of files) {
  // read file
}

for (let index in files) {
  // read files[index]
}
```

I also don't see a history reason, since [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) of [File](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) should have been around at least as long as FileList.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems you are totally spot on - from the [official specification](https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/#filelist-section):

> Note: The FileList interface should be considered "at risk" since the general trend on the Web Platform is to replace such interfaces with the Array platform object in ECMAScript [ECMA-262]. In particular, this means syntax of the sort filelist.item(0) is at risk; most other programmatic use of FileList is unlikely to be affected by the eventual migration to an Array type.

This interface is rather old and quite similar to [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) though the latter got modernized a bit.

Comment: Perfectly answering the question, thanks!